# How to use the parameter in Acumatica Report Designer to use in store procedure SQL Server?

Tags: acumatica

When I create report designer, it has 2parameters: StartDate and EndDate so if I want to use it in sql server store procedure so how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to use a stored procedure to build a temp table you will need to build a screen for your report which calls first the stored procedure and then second your report. If your report can be added to an existing page under a PXAction button this would also work. Look at VendorMaint for examples of this.

For an example on calling a stored procedure:

```
sp_MySP_Parms = new PXSPParameter[2];

//spParm1 and spParm2 must match your stored procedure parm names
PXSPInParameter parm1 = new PXSPInParameter("spParm1", "SomeValue1");
PXSPInParameter parm2 = new PXSPInParameter("spParm2", "SomeValue2");

sp_MySP_Parms[0] = parm1;
sp_MySP_Parms[1] = parm2;

object[] ret = PXDatabase.Execute("MySqlSPName", sp_MySP_Parms);
```

for an example on calling a report from a screen graph you can search the source for PXReportRequiredException. Here is an example from Vendor Maintenance calling a Balance by Vendor report:

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parameters["VendorID"] = vendor.AcctCD;
throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, "AP632500", AP.Messages.BalanceByVendor);
```